# Can you find a counterexample to this inequality statement?

Tags: inequality, examples-counterexamples

Let $x = (x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5)$ and $y = (y_1,y_2,y_3,y_4,y_5)$ be two vectors where each $x_i,y_i\in[0,1]$ and $\sum_{i}x_i = \sum_iy_i = 1$.

In addition, assume that the following conditions are true,
\begin{align}
y_1x_3&\le x_1y_3\\
y_1x_4&\le x_1y_4\\
y_1x_5&\le x_1y_5\\
y_2x_4&\le x_2y_4\\
y_2x_5&\le x_2y_5\\
y_3x_4&\le x_3y_4\\
y_3x_5&\le x_3y_5\\
y_4x_5&\le x_4y_5\\
\end{align}
Then, the following holds
\begin{align}
x_1+x_3+x_4+x_5&\le y_1+y_3+y_4+y_5\\
x_2+x_4+x_5&\le y_2+y_4+y_5\\
x_3+x_4+x_5&\le y_3+y_4+y_5\\
x_4+x_5&\le y_4+y_5\\
x_5&\le y_5
\end{align}

I have not been able to prove the above, and, as of yet, have also been unable to find a counterexample.

Comment: I just realized that the inequalities in my post form one big down arrow, please don't downvote! :)

Comment: you have not assigned anything for the determinants with index pairs 1,2  and 2,3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Counterexample:** If you set $x_1=y_2=1$, the rest of the variables have to be zero.

Now all of the top inequalities reduce to $0\le0$ and the first bottom inequality becomes $1\le0$.